# How can I make IE validation messages display like they do on Chrome or FIrefox?

Tags: html, css, validation, internet-explorer

IE has a different way of showing the default HTML validation messages. Chrome or Firefox, after submitting form, show pretty bubbles/tool tip with error message. IE underlines the invalid field, but the error message is showing only when the user hovers the field.

Is there any simple way to change how to display messages, similar to how Chrome does it?

Is this based on some pseudo-classes or something?

Comment: "IE underline invalid field, but error message is showing only when user hover field." Are you sure? Attempting to submit the form does cause IE to display a tooltip for me without having to hover the field.

Comment: Which version IE are you using?

Comment: IE11 on Windows 10. What about you? You should provide a test case.

Comment: I was testing on every IE10, IE11 and Edge and problem still occured. I will try to record a video to show how it looks

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear. By test case, I mean code, within the question. Not a video, although that would help us see how it looks for you.

Comment: No problem, I will edit post later, add my code html & typescript code (app in Angular2), but it's only submitting basic html5 form. :)

Comment: Can you add JSFiddle with your html? I have seen a sample HTML5 validations JSFiddle here  and even in IE I could see a tooltip being shown on form submit -don't need to hover on the control. Just the styling of tool tip and the input border on error are different in different browsers.  JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/girlie_mac/X6Uuc/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the oninvalid event.

```
document.getElementById('input').oninvalid = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //prevent default tooltip
  this.style.background = '#f2dede'; //whatever 
  var elem = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('tooltiptext')[0]; //select tooltip element

  //show the tooltip
  elem.style.visibility = "visible";
  elem.style.opacity = "1";
}
```

I made this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/petekeeports/0yxfj3Lr/, see if that is what you are looking for. Hope this helps!!